# Editing .classpath file looks correct in Eclipse but building fails

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have multiple multi-project Gradle builds composed of Java modules (Java 11), all of which build fine in Gradle from the command line. A dozen or so sub-projects in each multi-project tree and a dozen or so trees, for a total of 100+ projects. I'm able to use Gradle to import each multi-project builds into Eclipse just fine, but unfortunately, since the dependencies aren't in the same project tree they occur through maven jar artifacts rather than project dependencies. So, each multi-project tree is essentially isolated, unaware that all the projects it depends on are right there in the Eclipse workspace. This causes a variety of issues that don't exist with direct project dependencies including trouble locating source code and problems with building. I tried for a few hours to get BuildShip to deal with this situation and I was unable to get it to work. I think the issue has to do with its support of modules (even after figuring out the hacks required to get Gradle to handle modules).

Anyway, it's too much work to manually configure the buildpaths for all these projects to give them access to the projects that are not in their tree. So, I wrote a Perl script that processes all of the .classpath files that are generated by gradle for all of the project trees. This script looks for the kind="lib" entries and turns those into kind="src" entries.

Everything looks good in Eclipse! Exactly correct. I can see that the projects were added to the buildpath on the "Projects" tab. However, there's something subtle wrong and strange and non-repeatable compilation problems occur. Each time I remove all the projects, shutdown eclipse (with -clean option) and then reimport all the projects with fresh .classpath files, a DIFFERENT set of projects are unable to locate their dependent projects and fail with build errors related to not being able to find types.

I'm not sure that anyone will know how to solve this problem, but maybe someone can give me a clue. What I'm wondering is this: exactly how should these kind="src" class path entries look? I've tried many different combinations of attributes (including the attributes that Eclipse itself uses when you manually add an entry) and all I get is a perfect import into Eclipse and then Eclipse getting completely lost trying to build. Thanks.

-- Jon

Comment: You haven't shown anything to comment on.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support directly editing the .classpath file, it may have internal caches that won't be updated properly when you do this. Maybe doing a 'File > Refresh' would get everything updated.

Comment: Well that would explain it I guess. Thanks.